# recursively search and replace on command line with slashes?

Tags: perl

I need to run a search and replace command of something like:

```
s3.amazonaws.com/username/
```

changing to:

```
something.cloudfront.net
```

in the entire home directories folders and files like:

```
/home/username/
/home/username/folder
/home/username/folder/js
/home/username/folter/file.php    
etc.
```

How would I do that? The files are with different extensions like .php and .js, etc. so I need to replace all files like

```
*.*
```

I found a way to replace it via perl command line but it's not working because of the "/" slash.

```
perl -p -i -e 's/s3.amazonaws.com/username//something.cloudfront.net/g' `find ./ -name *`
```

Comment: Show us what you have so far so that we can help you fix it.

Comment: Are you trying to do this with Perl or PHP? You've tagged your question with both.

Comment: Sorry, with perl if possible or otherwise command line. Accidentally tagged php :)

Comment: Are you sure you want to remove the `/` that follows `s3.amazonaws.com/username`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example using curlie brackets as delimiters, and being more careful with the arguments from find. You have to watch out for spaces and special characters in the filenames, you know.

```
find . -type f -print0 |
   xargs -0 perl -i -pe's{\Qs3.amazonaws.com/username/}{something.cloudfront.net}g'
```

On POSIX systems, you don't even need `xargs`.

```
find . -type f -exec \
   perl -i -pe's{\Qs3.amazonaws.com/username/}{something.cloudfront.net}g' {} +
```

(The \Q makes the '.' character mean "one dot" as opposed to "one anything").

Comment: Just to be safe, you probably want to escape the periods in the search string as well to avoid matching any character: `s3\.amazonaws\.com/username/`

Comment: You're right, @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, I always forget that, I'll edit my answer, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Recursive file traversals in perl are best done with `File::Find`. This allows you to specify a callback - subroutine to execute on every file.

However, if you're really set on using perl-as-sed, can I point out that you can use a non slash as a delimiter.

```
s/somepattern/some_other_pattern/g;
```

is functionally equivalent to:

```
s,somepattern,some_other_pattern,g;
```

Or you can 'escape' the slash with a backslash, but I prefer using different delimiters for clarity.

So your pattern:

```
's/s3.amazonaws.com/username//something.cloudfront.net/g'
```

Would become:

```
's,s3.amazonaws.com/username/,something.cloudfront.net,g'
```

(Assuming I've got that middle 'slash' in the right place)